# Issue related to getting value from AJAX Call in Famo.us

Tags: javascript, jquery, famo.us

I am new in Famo.us framework. i have small Application in Famo.us framework.

I have following Code:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
    var Modifier = require('famous/core/Modifier');
    var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
    var View = require('famous/core/View');
    var HeaderFooterLayout = require('famous/views/HeaderFooterLayout');
    var App = require('./App');


    var apps = [];

    GetContent.prototype = Object.create(View.prototype);
    GetContent.prototype.constructor = GetContent;
    GetContent.DEFAULT_OPTIONS = {};

    function GetContent() {
        View.apply(this, arguments);
        GetData();
    }

    function GetData() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/LocalPlatFormService.svc/GetJobRCompanies",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: ajaxCallSucceed,
            dataType: "json"
        });
    }

    function ajaxCallSucceed(response) {
        var finalStr = '';
        var a = response[0].Success;
        if (a.toString().toLowerCase() == "true") {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                var strId = response[i].Id;
                var strSuccess = response[i].Success;
                finalStr += i + '.' + strId + ' , ' + strSuccess + ' ';

                var app1 = new App({});
                app1.AddPages(response[i].ImageLarge, response[i].Description, response.length, i);
                apps.push(app1);
            }
        }
        else {
            alert("No Data Found.");
        }
    }

    module.exports = GetContent;

});
```

The Ajax call in `GetData()` is works fine, and it also calls `ajaxCallSucceed()` on successful Call. but problem is that `ajaxCallSucceed()` executes after executing all other function, even after executing `module.exports = GetContent;` in last line.

I want to bind some values in `ajaxCallSucceed()` based on getting data from database 
but how to fetch value from `ajaxCallSucceed()`, as it is executing after all other operation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ajax async to false. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
async: false,
url: "/LocalPlatFormService.svc/GetJobRCompanies",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
success: ajaxCallSucceed,
dataType: "json"
```

});

Setting async to false means that the statement you are calling has to complete before the next statement in your function can be called. If you set async: true then that statement will begin it's execution and the next statement will be called regardless of whether the async statement has completed yet.